# Fetch all the links on a page that are within the same class

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

#### Quick Links

```
            <span class="buttonContainer"><input type="image" class="helpButton" src="/images/buttons/btn_help.gif" alt="View  help." title="View  help."><input type="image" class="minimizeButton" src="/businesscare/images/dashboard/btn_minus_white.gif" alt="Show less." aria-controls="tile-contents" aria-expanded="true" aria-live="polite"></span></dt>
            <dd>
                <strong>Help:</strong> Quickly access the tools you need to view your 
                             Name lists.
                        </dd>
        </dl>

        <div class="tile-contents">
            <div><strong>Note:</strong> links open a new window.</div>
            <div class="loading" style="display: none;">
                <div>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="configuration" style="display: none">
                <p>Choose and drag any transaction type to reorder your
                    shortcuts. Your top five shortcuts will be displayed by default in
                    the shaded area.</p>
                <hr>
                <ul class="dragable">
                </ul>                   
            </div>

            <h4>Links</h4>  
                    <ul class="contents">                       
                        <li><a href="Home" title="View home" onclick="openlink(this,this.title);return false;">View home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr>
                    <h4 id="Numbers">Numbers</h4>
                    <ul class="contents">                           
                        <li><a href="Link1" onclick="openlink(this,this.title);return false;">View Link1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Link2" title="View Link2" onclick="openlink(this,this.title);return false;">View Link2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Link3" title="View Link4" onclick="openlink(this,this.title);return false;">View Link3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr>

                    <h4 id="Photos">Photos</h4>                         
                    <ul class="contents">
                            <li><a href="Link4" title="Select Link4" onclick="openlink(this,this.title);return false;">Select Link4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <hr>

                    <h4 id="downloads">Downloads</h4>
                    <ul class="contents">
                        <li><a href="Link5" title="Download Link5" onclick="openlink(this,this.title);return false;">Download </a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr>

                    <h4 id="qlinkusers">Users</h4>
                    <ul class="contents">
                        <li><a href=Link6" title="View Link6" onclick="openlink(this,this.title);return false;">View Users</a></li>
                    </ul>                       
                </div>
    </li>
```

I need to fetch all the hrefs on the page and click them. I tried to fetch the links using the following code but the code returns empty list.

```
hRefs = []

parent = browser.find_element_by_class_name("contents")

links = parent.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
for link in links:
    hRefs.append(link)
print hRefs
```

This is what I get when I run the code an empty list.

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="386157b412d34905ae7344a206c156da", element="0.8337721961119238-2")>]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to fetch the links using @Niels-van-Reijmersdal code and was able to click the hrefs using the text.

```
hRefs = []

parent = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("contents")
for link in parent:
    links = link.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    for l in links:
        hRefs.append(str(l.text))
        browser.find_element_by_link_text(l.text).click()   
print hRefs
```

Comment: You can also just click on the element it self with l.click() no need to get the text first.

Answer (score 1):

It does not return an empty list, it returns a list with a single `<WebElement>`.

```
parent = browser.find_element_by_class_name("contents")
```

Only gives back the first content block, the provided HTML also shows it only has a single `<a>` tag. So the result is correct :)

Try this code to get all a_elements

```py
a_elements = []

content_blocks = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("contents")

for block in content_blocks:
    elements = block.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
    for el in elements:
        a_elements.append(el)

print a_elements
```

This should show all `<a>` elements in each content block. Still it wont show the hrefs, if you want those replace `append(element)` with `append(element.get_attribute("href"))`

```py
list_of_hrefs = []

content_blocks = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("contents")

for block in content_blocks:
    elements = block.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
    for el in elements:
        list_of_hrefs.append(el.get_attribute("href"))

print list_of_hrefs
```

Probably it is better to find with a CSS selector so you do not have to loop twice.

```
   elements = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".contents > a")
```

This should return all `<a>` elements under elements with a class `.contents`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Neils van Reijmesdal. 
The code was useful. I accepted your answer, can't up vote because I am a new to this forum.
The only problem that I see is there is a u prefixed to each element of the list, although when I loop over the list_of_hrefs and print the hrefs, the links text is displayed.

Comment: I used str(href) and I don't see the unicode character now. But still there is one last thing, in the list of hrefs, three hrefs are clubbed as one with a "\n" character. When I iterate over the list to click each href,  I get an error for the above mentioned list items that have \n.

['Link1', 'Link2\nLink3\nLink4', 'Link5', 'Link6']

Comment: That must be another page, cause it is missing the Home link. You can check if the string contains a \n and split() it and them. https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html